# How to find the equivalance class of an equivalance statement?

Tags: equivalence-relations

im fairly new to math and im trying to find all elements of equivalance class [-1] and [4/5] for the following equivalance relation

For a, b, c, d ∈ Z with b, d ≠ 0: a/b R c/d ⇔ ad = bc.

Ive deduced its an equivalent statement, being reflexive, symmetric and transitive but im unsure how to express the equivalent classes of [-1] and [4/5]?

Comment: *Hint* : express $-1$ as $\dfrac {-1}{1}$. We want the numbers $q= \dfrac c d$ such that $(-1)d = 1c$, i.e. $\dfrac c d = \dfrac {-1}{1}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so it would be {... (1,-1), (2,-2),(3-3)....}

Comment: Yes, all pairs $(c,d)$ such that $\dfrac c d = -1$. Thus, also $(-2,2)$ etc

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so would the class 4/5 be (4/5)/1 ?